# Ubuntu - can I use it or not

Tags: installation

I am from India and I have heard and read about Ubuntu. I am really sick of using Microsoft products. I want Ubuntu as a replacement. will it solve my needs.

I have tried downloading ubuntu. But I am facing problem. I can't locate the exact webpage or link. I think there are many version of ubuntu. Can someone help me in finding the link and also a step by step guide for installing it.

I have some other doubts. Will it have Office applications and internet browsers in its bundle or I have to download it separately.

Comment: Ubuntu is a fully featured OS and comes with Libre Office for word processing, spread sheet etc. Firefox is the default web browser.  Full instructions on how to install it are here: [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/107450)

Comment: In addition to that, you should know that -after download to a dvd or usb- you can boot ubuntu from there without actualy installing anything on your computer. This will tell you if ubuntu can deal with your hardware. If it all works, you can install it.

Answer (score 0):

Me to from india , and im using ubuntu from last 3 years back , Yes u can get it from the official website , Here is the Link [Official Site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

All u need to choose the Architecture before u Download for that may i know which motherboard u using and did it support 64 bit ?

Comment: How do I reply to your question. Thats Y i'm using this add comment option. Mother board is Intel Dual Core and I don't know whether it is 32 bit or 64 bit. In the system properties it will show as 32 bit

Comment: @Aravindhan: If in doubt go with the 32-bit version.  The 64-bit version only runs on 64-bit capable hardware. The 32-bit will run on both 64-bit capable hardware and 32-bit only hardware.  Try it without installing first to see if it all works.  If yes install, if no you can ask questions about anything that's not working.

Comment: Download and install Ubuntu 12.04 32bit Version